# Different Huber regression results between sklearn and statsmodels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am trying to apply a regression model robust to outliers. I used a Huber regression with both [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor.html) and [statsmodels](https://docs.w3cub.com/statsmodels/generated/statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.rlm) implementation.

I don't know why, but while the sklearn function gives the desired output, the statsmodels one just fits the data like a classic linear
regression.

Do you see something I did wrong with the statsmodels function?

sklearn code:

```
# sklearn
x = df["FSC-A"].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df["FSC-H"]

from sklearn.linear_model import HuberRegressor

model = HuberRegressor().fit(x, y)

# Find the slope and intercept of the best fit line
intercept = model.intercept_
slope = model.coef_[0]

print("------------")
print(f"slope : {slope}")
print(f"intercept : {intercept}")

------------
slope : 0.6615606986945426
intercept : 2.049139319468641e-07
```

statsmodels code:

```
# Test RLM
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = df["FSC-A"]
y = df["FSC-H"]

x2 = sm.add_constant(x)

rlm_model = sm.RLM(endog = y, 
                   exog= x2,
                   M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT())

rlm_results = rlm_model.fit()

print(rlm_results.params)

intercept =  rlm_results.params["const"]
slope = rlm_results.params["FSC-A"]

print("------------")
print(f"slope : {slope}")
print(f"intercept : {intercept}")

const    1.454894e+06
FSC-A    3.304745e-01
dtype: float64
------------
slope : 0.3304745435338382
intercept : 1454894.4713717608
```

Comment: are you sure you fitted the same data? The intercept is on totally different scales!

Comment: What are the residuals like from the two methods?  statsmodels doesn't include `sigma` in its definition: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/robust/norms.html#HuberT so the scale will likely matter.

Comment: Yes, this is the same dataset.